# Outlook 2010 Add-in not loaded after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I am new to outlook add-ins. I have developed one add-in to outlook in visual studio 2010 with c#.net for outlook 2010. I have developed form region and setup project also.

It works perfectly when I debug add-in from visual studio. However, if I install the add-in from `setupproject/bin/release/setup.exe` folder then nothing will happen.

It shows that setup is installed successfully but add-in does not appear when I start Outlook.
The `setup.exe` is also not working on another computer as well.

Comment: when you build the project are you changing the setting to point to the Release folder for starters..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes i am pointing to the Release folder for both. outlook add-in application also and setup project also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

and now my add-in is working fine in every computers.

I just publish my visual studio solution instead of setup project because my add-in contains form region. and the install the add-in via setup.exe from publish folder.

For those who wants to do like what i did, you can follow the steps to publish your add-in from this link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx

Mausami